# I'm on vacation in NYC. Can I visit/tour the Stack Exchange Headquarters?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange-hq

To make this question less localized:
**"If one is in New York City, is it possible to tour the Stack Exchange Headquarters?"**

---

Original Question (7/14/2012):

I live in Los Angeles (Orange County actually) and this is my first time in New York City!  My girlfriend and I are staying in a friends apartment on the upper east side of Manhattan; we have 7 day unlimited subway passes and are doing all the touristy stuff.  I thought it would be fun one afternoon to come say hi to the people that run my favorite network of sites.  My girlfriend knows Stack Overflow as "that site I am always on" and when I mentioned the idea to her she also thought it would be fun to visit the SE HQ.

So, can my girlfriend and I come tour the Stack Exchange office(s) sometime in the next few days while we are here in NYC?
(We are here until Wednesday (7/18) morning, so Monday or Tuesday would be perfect [assuming the offices are closed on weekends])

Comment: I can't see why you wouldn't be able to... I'd assume you just walk up to the reception desk and ask for a tour. If not, then you're just out of luck.

Comment: @yawus I don't know of many companies that offer a tour if you just show up

Comment: @simchona I guess it's an error of perception then. I live in an area with mostly large companies and they're always willing to give tours so long as you don't visit every week or so.

Comment: Your girlfriend thinks a trip to SEHQ would be fun?  Marry her!!!

Comment: Just ask for Joel.

Comment: You should *totally* propose to her through a message running on the [Stack Big Board](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/the-stack-big-board/) …

Comment: Just don't propose to her on StackOverflow itself. That usually doesn't go over well.

Comment: @simchona, usually? That implies you have experience of this! More than once... :-)

Comment: @chown I hope she provides an acceptable answer to your question.

Comment: @Ben: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424226/this-is-weird-but-serious-this-is-not-a-joke Get 3,000 more reputation, and you can see it :)

Comment: @chown then it's like a bounty.

Comment: @simchona, over half of the proposal don't end well, so the fair advice would be to skip that part altogether.

Comment: Dangit, I was in NYC three weeks ago.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Generally, the answer is "no".  Most of the people working out of New York are sales people who **cannot be interrupted or we will run out of money and have to stop sending out so many free t-shirts**.  We don't really have anyone whose job it is to show people around the office.

With that said, you can always try sending an email.  If someone in the office recognizes you from the site and feels like showing you around we can try to set something up.

Also, definitely don't try to "just stop by" -- building security won't let you in (that's kind of their job).

Comment: Even if I show up with Stack Exchange T-shirt and covered with stickers? ;)

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18187/is-it-possible-to-go-on-a-tour-of-the-stack-exchange-headquarters new question on travel.se is this situation same,could u post email so that i can elaborate my answer over there which serve as an reference for future visitors

Comment: What about the London office?

Comment: @david-fullerton Who would you sent the email to?