# Stack Exchange offices around the world

Tags: discussion

I found an article about Google offices [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-offices-googleplex-around-the-world-photos/) and [here](https://www.google.com/about/company/facts/locations/).

- What are all the offices of Stack Exchange around the world?
- Is that possible to represent Stack Overflow for example in my
  country or not, if so how is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are all the offices of Stack Exchange around the world?

As far as I know, there are three offices:

- Stack Overflow HQ: New York ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139800/245360))
- London (where Oded works for example, more positions currently in the [*We're hiring* section](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here#positions), which shows more than just development happening there)
- Denver (small office, primarily sales, [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272419/245360))

> Is that possible to represent Stack Overflow for example in my country or not, if so how is that?

That is not a very concrete question. How do you mean 'represent'? You can obviously work for SO from your country, as a lot of employees work from their own place, like [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) works from the Philippines. SO doesn't have representatives in every country and you can't speak for them unless you are part of them (you work there).

Comment: Actually, I work remote. I only come into the office when I feel like it (which is about once every other week or so).

Comment: At least you have an office nearby. What about Tim?

Comment: Ha, no such luck, no. We have people across Europe too (France, Germany, Slovenia, Spain to name a few), the closest office they have is the London office. It might be the closest one to Tim (though the Denver one might be closer - didn't check).